# Excel: Sum values in column if value in same row, different column is odd

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to sum values in column X which correspond to an odd number in column K and sum values in column X which correspond to an even number in column K. I need them summed separately has I am then going to multiply them either by A or (A-1) depending if they have odd or even correspondence, respectively. So essentially I end up the formula: A*(SUM of numbers with ODD correspondence) + (A-1)(SUM of numbers with EVEN Correspondence).

[image]

I have tried using variations of `SUMIF` with `ISODD()` and the best I have gotten is a dynamic array of "TRUE" or "FALSE"

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
=LET(
  a,5,
  factor,IF(MOD(K3:K16,2)=0,a-1,a),
  SUMPRODUCT(factor,X3:X16)
)
```

Where `a=5` in this example (replace as necessary)

[image]

Edit: To automatically adjust the row count, format the range as a Table, then supposing the table is named Table1 the formula becomes:

```
=LET(
  a,5,
  factor,IF(MOD(Table1[Layer '#],2)=0,a-1,a),
  SUMPRODUCT(factor,Table1[Length of Load Line '[in']])
)
```

Comment: This works if I only select the rows with data. However, in this particular case, the spreadsheet calculates the number of rows based on user input; therefore, the formula needs to be able to calculate empty rows.

Comment: I've edited to advise use of Tables which will auto-adjust the range.

Comment: I tried to make that edit a minute ago and I get the #VALUE! error. For now, I've added two more columns to the table to collect the odd and even data. It's kind of a clunky solution, and not what I wanted, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the formulas are helpful.

On my example, to get SUM of numbers with ODD correspondence, `=SUM(IF(MOD(K2:K6,2),X2:X6,0))`; SUM of numbers with EVEN Correspondence, `=SUM(IF(MOD(K2:K6,2),0,X2:X6))`.

[image]

Comment: This works if each cell has a value. For a table with blanks or zeros, this unfortunately does not work.